# How to make a new JSON string from original string by extracting few fields from it?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON String like this:

```
{"customerid":null,"clientid":"123456","test_id":"98765","pet_id":0,"qwer_id":0,"timestamp":1411811583000}
```

I need to make another JSON String like this:

```
{"customerid":"System.nanoTime()","test_id":"98765","timestamp":1411811583000}
```

So basically given an original JSON String, I need to extract "customerid", "test_id" and "timestamp" only and then make a new JSON string out of it. Also, value of "customerid" in new json I will make value of `System.nanoTime()`.

Below is my code:

```
JsonObject originalJSONString = new JsonObject();

// some code here

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(originalJSONString));

// make a new JSON String now
```

I am using GSON in my example. I am confuse how to extract relevant fields which I am interested from original json and then make a new json out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `originalJSONString` represents

```
{"customerid":null,"clientid":"123456","test_id":"98765","pet_id":0,"qwer_id":0,"timestamp":1411811583000}
```

you can try with something like

```
JsonObject newJsonObject = new JsonObject();

newJsonObject.addProperty("customerid", "System.nanoTime()");//new property
newJsonObject.add("test_id", originalJSONString.get("test_id"));//copy property
newJsonObject.add("timestamp", originalJSONString.get("timestamp"));//copy property

System.out.println(gson.toJson(newJsonObject));
```

Output: `{"customerid":"System.nanoTime()","test_id":"98765","timestamp":1411811583000}`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the JSON string to a map and then get only the key/values that you need.

something like:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;

....

//convert JSON string to Map    
map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});

...

//add key and values in a new one    
JsonObject newJsonObject = new JsonObject();
```